# Titanium forgedUI: application crashing with no apparent reason

Tags: android, exception, titanium-mobile

I've been testing the new [ForgedUI](http://www.forgedui.com/) add-on for Titanium that helps create UI elements for the Titanium applications.

I created the UI and built it to JS code. and it now looks like [this](http://pastie.org/3089477), tnd the app.js look like [this](http://pastie.org/3089481)

however, when I build the app for my device I get the following error:

```
`12-29 10:28:54.745: E/TiAPI(20029): --------added
 12-29 10:28:54.764: E/TiAPI(20029): --------window created
 12-29 10:28:54.764: E/TiAPI(20029): -------logo created
 12-29 10:28:54.768: E/TiAPI(20029): -------searchbar created
 12-29 10:28:54.772: E/TiAPI(20029): -------BT1 created
 12-29 10:28:54.776: E/TiAPI(20029): -------BTN2 created
 12-29 10:28:54.776: E/TiAPI(20029): ------- appSTUDIO logo created
 12-29 10:28:54.780: E/TiAPI(20029): -------Bug report pic created
 12-29 10:28:54.780: E/TiAPI(20029): ---------window created
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029): (main) [14,192] Sending event: exception on      thread: main msg:java.lang.NumberFormatException: Unable to convert java.lang.Boolean; Titanium 1.8.0.1,2011/12/22 13:09,fbdc96f
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Unable to convert java.lang.Boolean
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at   org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert.toInt(TiConvert.java:307)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert.toInt(TiConvert.java:313)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIText.handleKeyboard(TiUIText.java:297)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIText.processProperties(TiUIText.java:145)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.searchbar.TiUISearchBar.processProperties(TiUISearchBar.java:93)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.setModelListener(KrollProxy.java:641)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:449)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:441)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:427)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:456)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at ti.modules.titanium.ui.ActivityWindowProxy.handleMessage(ActivityWindowProxy.java:81)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 12-29 10:28:55.128: E/TiApplication(20029):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Unable to convert java.lang.Boolean
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert.toInt(TiConvert.java:307)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert.toInt(TiConvert.java:313)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIText.handleKeyboard(TiUIText.java:297)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIText.processProperties(TiUIText.java:145)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.searchbar.TiUISearchBar.processProperties(TiUISearchBar.java:93)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.setModelListener(KrollProxy.java:641)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:449)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleGetView(TiViewProxy.java:441)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.getOrCreateView(TiViewProxy.java:427)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.realizeViews(TiViewProxy.java:456)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.ActivityWindowProxy.handleMessage(ActivityWindowProxy.java:81)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 12-29 10:28:55.174: E/AndroidRuntime(20029):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 12-29 10:28:55.182: E/(482): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

`

thanks all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason Titanium doesn't recognize these lines anymore and therefor crashed immediately after using them.
after erasing them the app worked perfectly.

```
autocapitalization  : false,
autocorrect         : false
```

I'll post a bug report on Titanium's website.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue leading back to the same, seemingly buggy behaviour of autocapitalization.

Digging around a bit further it seems autocapitalization shouldn't hold a true or false value (which does work perfectly in iOS, just not in Android). Instead it should hold contsant values as defined here :

[autocapitalization constants](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TextField.autocapitalization-property.html)

For autocorrect, it seems we can just set it to true or false. I now have the following lines in my textfields working on Android as well as iOS without any issues :

```
autocaptalization: Ti.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_NONE,
autocorrect: false,
```